# How can I add a json as part of a url?

Tags: php, json

The question seems quite simple, but I've tried everything that I've read and nothing worked
I have this example url: localhost/test/{"user":"test","password":"test"}   so, that json is part of the url how can I add it? I tried the following things

```
 $arrayVariable =  array (
        "Usuario"  => "user",
        "Clave" => "test"

    );
    $res = json_encode($arrayVariable);
```

but the answer of $res is the following

```
"{\"Usuario\":\"user\",\"Clave\":\"test\"}"
```

I've tried str_replace to remove backslashed but it didn't work, I tried the following two functions

```
$res  = str_replace("\\","",$res)
$res = str_replace("\\\\","",$res)
```

but it didn't work because seems the backslash is part of the " quote

Edit: I can't change the url because is an external API so nothing I can do that way

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: We're using an external API and the url is like that,  I can make it work without problem on postman but I can't build the url on php

Comment: Shouldn't https://3v4l.org/ciRCs

Comment: You can [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)  function.

```
$arrayVariable =  array (
        "Usuario"  => "user",
        "Clave" => "test"

    );
    $res = urlencode(json_encode($arrayVariable));
```

But i think you should re-think your logic since this is a very unusual thing to do.